# EditorTemplate Naming Convention for Collection model classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, razor-2

I have a model property that is declared as type `List<MyClass>`.

```
public class MyModel
{
    List<MyClass> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to display/edit the property using Razor templates. My question is, how I name an EditorTemplate view so that I can display the property using the normal syntax:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

I know that I can create a view called MyClass.cshtml that will be used for the type `MyClass`, but how do I create a template for the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `[UIHint]` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("TemplateForTheList")]
    public List<MyClass> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

or specify the template name as second parameter to the `DisplayFor` helper:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProperty, "TemplateForTheList")
```

and then have a `TemplateForTheList.cshtml` template:

```
@model List<MyClass>
...
```

In this case the templating engine will not render the template for each element of the collection property. It will simply pass the collection itself to the template.