# MVC EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I create Editor Templates for `Date`, `DateTime` and `Time`, how do I differentiate between `Date` and `DateTime`?

Currently by Entity Model shows data from SQL Server that is stored as `Date` and `DateTime` both as my `DateTime` EditorTemplate.

I have tried

```
@model System.DateTime?
```

and

```
@model System.DateTime
```

I understand it is because C# only has `DateTime` and not `Date` like SQL Server.

Any quick ways around it?

Comment: You have to work with types that exist in C#, and name the templates after those. If that is not enough, you'll need to call the templates explicitly providing the template name.

Comment: Expected that. Hoped I didn't have to call it explicitly

Comment: It might be that [`UIHint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941052/11683) works for you.

Comment: Interesting. Will play with it a bit

Comment: Worked like a charm!